# creating own bootstrap in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, bootstrapping

I am trying to create the bootstrap file in php.
index.php file is my bootstrap file under root directory.

```
define('ROOT',getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
function url(){
  return sprintf(
    "%s://%s%s",
    isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http',
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
  );
}
```

Here, I have above code to get root directory and base url in all php file. so, I have .htaccess file to redirect to index.php for all request.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On

#  Redirect to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I have created php file for testing bootstrap(test.php)

```
<?php
echo ROOT." ".url();
?>
```

I browse as http://localdomain.com/HRPayroll/test.php 
Here,The page shows error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function url()
```

Here, I want to redirect all request through index.php. In this case, I want to print the return value of url() in above url test.php
What is wrong with this, am I doing it correctly to create bootstrap?

Comment: Create bootstrap, you say. Bootstrap is a CSS library made up of multiple files, and "creating" it makes no sense whatsoever. You're gonna need to clarify.

Comment: @Ariane that's Twitter Bootstrap. Bootstrapping is just a series of events at the start up of an application.

Comment: @FDL Oh, that's what it meant. I've been seeing THAT bootstrap so much I was completely forgetting the word itself. I'm embarrassed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include('bootstrap.php');
echo ROOT." ".url();
?>
```

Or http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

index.php

```
define('ROOT',getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
function url(){
  return sprintf(
    "%s://%s%s",
    isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http',
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
  );
}
include('test.php');
```

test.php

```
<?php
echo ROOT." ".url();
?>
```

And 
 http://localdomain.com/HRPayroll/ (becouse of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`)

Comment: I think you don't understand my question. Here, index.php is bootstrap file. I want to redirect all request to single file that is index.php so that I can get the value of base url. Same way I can have code for database connection in bootstrap file and other code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like cske already has the solution but I just wanted to add that to debug this kind of thing and fix future problems you can do one of these:

1. Check in your Apache logs for errors.
2. run you .php file from the command line and look at errors being output.
3. Add debugging to your code and output information to the webpage. For example, with the problem you have here you could call http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php and either print "true" or "false" on the webpage.
4. add a debug class to your code and write debug information to a file rather than directly to the webpage, you can then debug after your code goes live if you need to.

You should also set http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php so that you get all errors output.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function url(). Actually here I want is automatically load all code of index.php to all request php file without using include or require function in that all file.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

mean requested resource is not a file , but test.php is actually a file and it will load it .

If you want to implement sth like Controller, views etc , remove test file from the root directory and place that somewhere accessible through index.php

index.php

```
define('ROOT',getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

function takeAction($className,$method,$args=array()){
   $path="protected/class.{$className}.php"; 
   if(file_exists($path)){
       include_once($path);
       $instance=new $className();
       $instance->$method($args);
   }else
      throw new Exception('Invalid  resource .... ');      
}

$className=isset($_GET['className']) ? $_GET['className'] : 'defaultClass';
$action=isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : 'index';
$params=$_GET; //

takeAction($className,$action,$params);
```

You should have some conventions to translate your url e.g

```
 http://www.mydomain.com/[className]/[action]/[parameter]
```

A best tutorial for you would be [zend router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html)

Of course this is not tested /working code